# Have Jenkins execute a build step if any files in a certain directory have been modified since last commit (not FS trigger)

Tags: jenkins

I'm setting up my first Jenkins server as an interesting little project and to make my life easier

It executes a build of a Play Framework application when a commit to my bitbucket repo occurs and will launch the application successfully

I'd like to add a step in the process whereby if any .sql file in the $WORKSPACE/sql directory has been created or updated in the last commit, that sql file will be executed against our database.

The actual execution should be simple enough theoretically - execute a shell command.. But I'm not sure how to set up jenkins to perform the check 'is there any new or changed sql files in this directory'

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Tim

Answer (score 0):

So I might need to refine this yet but I've tackled it using shell commands

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD | grep -i .sql | while read -r line; do
echo "processing $line"
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S <redacted> -U sa -P <redacted> -d <redacted> -i $WORKSPACE/$line
done
```

So  what this is doing is using git diff-tree to list all changed files in the commit, grep is then filtering the sql files. We then loop through and (in my case as its mssql server) use sqlcmd to then execute the script on the database